# Extract links from document jsoup containing some string to other string

Tags: java, android, parsing, jsoup

i use [jsoup](http://www.jsoup.org) to extract the links from a website. i want to extract one only specified link containg some keywords. i want to retrieve the links contains the keyword "download". how to do it. i have the following code

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse( new URL("http://www.examplesite.com)); 
Element link = doc.select("a").first();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) for the selector syntax.

You can test for the text within a node with `:contains`, e.g. `Element link = doc.select("a:contains(Download)").first();`. If you want you can use `:matches` for regex.

You get the link address via the `attr` method, e.g. `String linkaddress = link.attr("href");`.

Comment: also i would like to convert to string.?

Comment: in the doc i get to matches(jsoup finds 2 links, the same links), is it possible to get only the first one and convert to a string? thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
elements with attributes that start with [attr^=value],end with [attr$=value],contain the value [attr*=value] e.g. [href*=/path/]
```

you want to get the links containing certain word use this

```
org.jsoup.select.Elements links = doc.select("[href*=download]");
```